# How can I import CPLEX in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, cplex

I am new to Python and Jupyter notebook. I am using Windows 10.

I already installed Anaconda3 and tried to import cplex in Jupyter notebook environment.
But I only got the below error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'cplex'

[image: error]

I did find some resolutions for that, but neither of them fixed the problem.

I think I have to set path or install something for using the CPLEX in Jupyetr notebook, but I cannot find how I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html

[image]

You could use the Docplex api: http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/getting_started_python.html

You could even start without installing cplex on your machine. (But call cplex in the cloud https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/try-docloud-free/)

And you could also use docplex in Watson Studio: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/DO/DOcplex.html